# Is there any solution that can show SVG without HTML tags using Flask?

Tags: python, flask, web, svg, backend

Is there any solution that can show SVG without HTML tags using Flask?

I'm building project similar to [this project](https://github.com/DenverCoder1/github-readme-streak-stats),which  allow user to show their current stats on their static website by generating image(in SVG) user's stats .

According to my understanding, the concept is:

1. using GET parameters to specify user's data , theme, etc.
2. the server query the user's data
3. the server return an SVG with user's data

Example from the repository:
https://github-readme-streak-stats.herokuapp.com/?user=DenverCoder1

The result of the example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvLwS.png

I wrote the back-end in Python with Flask.

However, I can't find a solution to show only SVG using Flask.

I have tried `render_template()` method or `return` raw string of SVG. Neither of them could show only SVG without HTML tag.

1. using `render_template()`

```py
@app.route("/test_rend" , methods=['GET'])
def Test_rend():
    ...
    
    return render_template("img.svg")
```

2. return raw string of SVG

```py
@app.route("/test_raw" , methods=['GET'])
def Test_raw():
    ...
    
    return '''
    <svg width="100px" height="100px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

        <rect height="100%" width="100%" fill="white" />

            <circle cx="50%" cy="45%" r="40%" fill-opacity="0" style="stroke:green; stroke-width:6%; " />

            <text x="20%" y="47%" fill="blue" font-size="1.3em" font-weight="bold">ZERO</text>

            <text x="26%" y="65%" fill="blue" font-size="1em" font-weight="900" >JUDGE</text>


            <line x1="5%" y1="10%" x2="95%" y2="10%" style="stroke:white; stroke-width:30%; "/>

            <line x1="5%" y1="20%" x2="95%" y2="20%" style="stroke:green; stroke-width:10%; "/>

            <line x1="5%" y1="25%" x2="95%" y2="25%" style="stroke:white; stroke-width:5%; "/>
    </svg>
    '''
```

The result of both code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYr3V.png

Is there any solution that can show SVG without HTML tags using Flask?

Comment: Now create `test.htm` with just `<div class="test">Test</div>`, open it in browser and check source. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg9Uz.jpg).

Comment: Sorry , I didn't describe my issue precisely . I want to find a way to return only `SVG` on my page without `HTML` tag like https://i.imgur.com/Kc9hMzT.png using flask.

Comment: You do this, but browser add other tags automatically. That's what I've tried to highlight in first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to serve the data as a pure SVG file, it is necessary to define the mimetype of the response. The browser thus identifies the file using the 'Content-Type' header and interprets it correctly.

This example shows the use of raw data.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    svg = '''
    <svg width="100px" height="100px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <rect height="100%" width="100%" fill="white" />
        <circle cx="50%" cy="45%" r="40%" fill-opacity="0" style="stroke:green; stroke-width:6%; " />
        <text x="20%" y="47%" fill="blue" font-size="1.3em" font-weight="bold">ZERO</text>
        <text x="26%" y="65%" fill="blue" font-size="1em" font-weight="900" >JUDGE</text>
        <line x1="5%" y1="10%" x2="95%" y2="10%" style="stroke:white; stroke-width:30%; "/>
        <line x1="5%" y1="20%" x2="95%" y2="20%" style="stroke:green; stroke-width:10%; "/>
        <line x1="5%" y1="25%" x2="95%" y2="25%" style="stroke:white; stroke-width:5%; "/>
    </svg>
    '''
    return app.response_class(svg, mimetype='image/svg+xml')
```

Using `render_template` it would look like this.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return app.response_class(
        render_template('img.svg'),
        mimetype='image/svg+xml'
    )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is what I want to accomplish !